# Evitar que se duplique la lista al llamar a json

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hago una web con `Asp.net mvc` y `sql server` engo una tabla que al presionar un boton me va creando las demas filas a traves de `jquery`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me va agrendado dos imagenes que al hacer click elimina y la otra me saca una ventana modal con una lista de productos. El problema es que cada que hago click en la lupa me duplica los items, al hacer click por primera vez me mustra 10, al segundo me muestra 20 y asi sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo para crear las filas:

```
 $("#img-add").on("click", function () {
            $("#tablaProductos tbody:last-child").append("<tr><td hidden><input class='form-control datosfact idinput' /></td> " +
                "<td><input class='form-control datosfact'/></td>" +
                "<td><input class='form-control datosfact' /></td>" +
                "<td><input class='form-control datosfact'/></td> " +
                "<td><input class='form-control datosfact'/></td> " +
                "<td><input class='form-control datosfact'/></td> " +
                "<td class='td-centrada'><img src='/svg/trash-can-red.svg' alt='Eliminar' class='img-sgv img-delete' /> " +
                " <img src='/svg/search-green.svg' alt='Buscar' class='img-sgv img-search' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalProduc'/> </td ></tr > ");
        });
```

y con este llamo al modal y a la lista

```
  $(document).on('click', '.img-search', e => {
        $.ajax({
            //url: 'Ventas/spProductos' + $('input[name=TelCelular]').val(),
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Ventas/spProductos',
            dataType: "json",
            /*method: 'GET',*/
            success: function (json) {
                var table = $('#modalProduc').find('.table tbody');
                for (var i in json) {
                    tabla = json;
                    table.append('<tr><td hidden class="idpr">' + json[i].idProducto + '</td><td>' + json[i].referProd + '</td><td>' + json[i].nombreProd + '</td><td> <buttton class="btn btn-warning datosfact form-control bselec"> Seleccionar </button></td></tr>');
                }
              
            }
        });

    });
```

¿como evito que cada que se presione la lupa me lo duplique?

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que entres a la función a la cual dirige la lupa, primero limpia la tabla, segun tu código seria asi:

```
$(document).on('click', '.img-search', e => {
    $.ajax({
        //url: 'Ventas/spProductos' + $('input[name=TelCelular]').val(),
        type: "GET",
        url: 'Ventas/spProductos',
        dataType: "json",
        /*method: 'GET',*/
        success: function (json) {
            var table = $('#modalProduc').find('.table tbody');
            table.empty();
            for (var i in json) {
                tabla = json;
                table.append('<tr><td hidden class="idpr">' + json[i].idProducto + '</td><td>' + json[i].referProd + '</td><td>' + json[i].nombreProd + '</td><td> <buttton class="btn btn-warning datosfact form-control bselec"> Seleccionar </button></td></tr>');
            }
          
        }
    });

});
```